# Force Eclipse not to Refactor → Rename the whole workspace

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, project, rename, workspace

I have an Eclipse workspace with two or more projects, based on the same code (meaning that they have variable/function names that are the same). When I try to use *Refactor* → *Rename*, Eclipse will by default rename every instance of the variable/function in the whole workspace, which is not desirable. Can I tell Eclipse to only refactor things in the current project?

I have already done some work on this with Call Hierarchy with Working Sets, but I can't find such an option for Refactor.

I'm using the following Eclipse for C/C++ version on Mac OS 10.12.6:

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Build id: 20150924-1200

Answer (score 0):

Best choice I can think of is to close one project, and do the refactoring on the other.